# Make sure that string follows the required format

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, substr

I am attempting to check if a string follows a certain format by checking that:

- `item[]=` is repeated four times
- `item[]=` is followed by a number and `&` symbol (e.g `item[]=2&`), except the last number doesn't have `&` after it
- The numbers after `item[]=` consist of only either 1-4 and can be in any order, but not repeated

Here are a few examples of how the string would look (as you can see, the order of the number changes) - note that there will only be one string at a time!

1)

```
$list = 'item[]=1&item[]=3&item[]=2&item[]=4';
```

2)

```
$list = 'item[]=3&item[]=1&item[]=4&item[]=2';
```

3)

```
$list = 'item[]=4&item[]=3&item[]=2&item[]=1';
```

This is how far I've got:

```
// check item[]= is repeated four times
if(substr_count($list, "item[]=") == '4') {

   // strip the string to only numbers, then will need to check each number if between 1-4
   $numbers = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$list);

   // strip the string to only numbers and the character after it, will need to ensure it is & (except for the last number)
   preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$list + 1);

}
```

Comment: So you've completely ignored my suggestions from when you asked this earlier today?

Comment: @MarkBaker Hi Mark, I did point out that after you had posted your comment, I realised that I had missed some of the criteria out from my question.

Comment: And you aren't familiar with PHP's max() and min() functions: `parse_str($list, $output); if (isset($output['item']) && count($output['item']) == 4 && count(array_unique($output['item'])) == 4 && min($output['item']) == 1 && max($output['item']) == 4) { echo 'All OK!'; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$list    = 'item[]=1&item[]=3&item[]=2&item[]=4';
$pattern = "/^(item\[\]=[1-4])(&(item\[\]=[1-4])){3}$/";

if (preg_match($pattern, $list)) {
    // check for repetition
    $matches = [];
    preg_match_all("/\d+/", $list, $matches);

    if (count(array_count_values($matches[0])) == 4) {
        // All are unique values
        echo 'All conditions met';
    }
}
```

Comment: 1-4 and can be in any order, **but not repeated**

Comment: Hello, seem to get this error `preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash -- at line 9`

Comment: @TheCodesee Sorry, forgot to include `/`. Updated answer

Comment: @Jomoos That's alright, but your code isn't displaying 'All conditions met'

Comment: @TheCodesee Updated

Comment: @TheCodesee Try using `([1-9]|10|11|12)` instead of `[1-12]`

Comment: @TheCodesee `$pattern = "/^(item\[\]=([1-9]|10|11|12))(&(item\[\]=([1-9]|10|11|12))){11}$/";`

Comment: May I ask what `{3}` did and now `{11}` does?

Comment: @TheCodesee `{11}` tells `(&(item\[\]=([1-9]|10|11|12)))‌` has to be repeated `11` times. [See this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Comment: If I had `(&(item\[\]=([1-9]|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32|33)))‌` would `{11}` stay the same, or have to be changed?