# Why is my preg_match_all not working?

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am using `preg_match_all` to ensure that a string follows a certain pattern.

It should display 'all conditions are met' becuase the string follows the pattern, but instead, it displays 'conditions net met'.

```
$order = "item[]=2&item[]=1&item[]=3&item[]=4&item[]=5&item[]=6&item[]=7&item[]=8&item[]=9&item[]=10&item[]=11&item[]=12";
$pattern = "/^(item\[\]=([1-9]|10|11|12))(&(item\[\]=([1-9]|10|11|12))){11}$/";

if(preg_match($pattern, $order)) {

   // check for repetition
   $matches = [];
   preg_match_all("/\d+/", $order, $matches);
   if(count(array_count_values($matches[0])) == 12) {
      // All are unique values
      echo 'All conditions met';
   }
}else{
   echo 'Conditions not met';
}
```

Comment: Your `$pattern` regex is incomplete, did you post the one you are using?

Comment: Your input string looks like a query string. I would use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to put the values into an array and then check the constraints against the array. It's much easier.

Comment: this is a similar story of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42679522/make-sure-that-string-follows-the-required-format and there was solution from @AbraCadaver. You should learn and use `parse_str` function

Comment: @axiac I suppose you're right. I will take a look at this function.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest It's a shame because he later deleted his answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I've posted my fuil code here.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/0wzQ6a/1, your regex is wrong.

Comment: ["All conditions met"](https://ideone.com/9t8cyl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way would be using 
`parse_str`(to parse *quesry string*: key/value pairs separated with `&`) 
and `array_diff`(to check if all numbers from the needed range `1-12` are present and not repeated) functions:

```
$order = "item[]=2&item[]=1&item[]=3&item[]=4&item[]=5&item[]=6&item[]=7&item[]=8&item[]=9&item[]=10&item[]=11&item[]=12";
parse_str($order, $items);

if (isset($items['item']) && is_array($items['item'])
    && count($items['item']) == 12 && !array_diff(range(1, 12), $items['item'])) {
    echo 'All conditions met';
} else {
    echo 'Conditions not met';
}
```

Comment: Should I post this answer also on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42679522/make-sure-that-string-follows-the-required-format/ or would you like to?

Comment: @TheCodesee, I think it's not nessesary, but you can specify "related to" in each of the questions to make this questions linked. Like *cross-linking*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$order = "item[]=2&item[]=1&item[]=3&item[]=4&item[]=5&item[]=6&item[]=7&item[]=8&item[]=9&item[]=10&item[]=11&item[]=12";
$pattern = "/^(item\[\]=([1-9]|10|11|12))(&(item\[\]=([1-9]|10|11|12))){11}$/";

if(preg_match($pattern, $order)) {

   // check for repetition
   $matches = [];
   preg_match_all("/\d+/", $order, $matches);
   if(count(array_count_values($matches[0])) == $movienumber) {
       // All are unique values
       echo 'All conditions met';
    }
}else{
   echo 'Conditions not met';
}
```

You were missing a `)` in pattern.

Comment: Sorry, thats simply a mistake when I posted the code here - the `)` is there and I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input string is valid (all conditions are met) when it contains in `item[]` all the values from `1` to `12`, this simple piece of code works faster than `preg_match()` and it's easier to understand:

```
// Input string
$order = "item[]=2&item[]=1&item[]=3&item[]=4&item[]=5&item[]=6&item[]=7&item[]=8&item[]=9&item[]=10&item[]=11&item[]=12";

// Parse it to values and store them in $pieces
$pieces = array();
parse_str($order, $pieces);

// Need to sort the values to let the comparison succeed
sort($pieces['item']);
$valid = ($pieces['item'] == range(1, 12));

// Verification
var_dump($valid);
// It prints:
// bool(true)
```